# how can i skip range from for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have coded skip one character, but I wanna skip range of character "b" to "g".

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(97,110) if i!=99] 
print(alphabet)
```

#output

```
['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Comment: [chr(i) for i in range(97,110) if i not in range(98,104)]

Comment: `if i >=someint and i <=someint`

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[:1] + string.ascii_lowercase[7:]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> [chr(i) for i in range(97,110) if not (98 <= i <= 103)]
['a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

You can check if the value `i` is between 98 and 103 and use `not` on that.

Or, without any if condition:

```
>>> [chr(97)] + [chr(i) for i in range(104, 110)]
['a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(97,110) if chr(i) not in "bcdefg"] 
print(alphabet)
```